# Invalid character found in the request target Tomcat 9

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jsp, tomcat

In the migration of a project that works correctly under Tomcat 7 to Tomcat 9 I am receiving the error Invalid character found in the request target when passing words with accents in the request.

The server.xml file was modified by introducing in the connector `URIEncoding="UTF-8`" and the clause `relaxedQueryChars= áÁéÉíÍóÓúÚ` was also introduced, but I still receive the same error. I can't touch the actual code of the project.

log traces show this: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in the request target [/sahab/lupaDem.do?filtro=LupaDem&param1=1&param2=29527&param3=OBSERVACI0xd3N%20ANTIRR0xc1BICA`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP does not allow to specify an encoding for the requested path. Thus in the past servers used OS settings which were actually confusing especially for applications used world-wide.

Therefore the standard established to always encode requests as UTF-8, and even then there is the URLEncoding which would prevent UTF-8 problems by %-escaping any special characters.

In a nutshell, ensure your requests are properly encoded. Previous versions of Tomcat may not have errored on this. The requests are coming from the client, not the server itself.